# get only divs that have two specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get only the div that have two `classes` and not just one.

The problem that in have tried it with jQuery that give me all `divs` that have one of the classes.

```html
<div class='one'></div>
<div class='two'></div>
<div class='one two'>I just want to get this</div>
```

```
$('.one .two').html('ok');
```

this code return all three divs

Comment: Just remove the space between the two names - `.one.two`

Comment: try this => `$('.one.two').html('ok');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get just both classes you shouldn't add space between them in jquery selector

```
$('.one.two').html('ok');
```